# Create a JFrame from a class and take input from it

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe, joptionpane

I'm a little confused by how to achieve what I want to implement. In my main Java class I want to be able to call multiple JFrames for things like settings. I have the GUI in the main class set up; I want my buttons to call separate JFrames and then capture the user input, returning it to the main class for processing. Like this:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
     public Main(){}

     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               new Settings();
          }
     });
}

public class Settings extends JFrame{
     submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               //Capture data and return it to main
          }
     });
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm going to right way about this. I want all my little popups in different Java files for ease of use.

Comment: Are these settings going to need to persist when the application exits?

Answer (score 3):

I think you do not need JFrame for settings.
In Java there is an Object like JOptionPane and that is what you need.
Here you got my example:

```
String[] levels = {"Easy", "Medium", "Gomoku"};
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Choose level:", "OX Level",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, levels, levels[0]);
```

Here you got good tutorial: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a lot of settings that the user will need to tweak (10+) so I thought making a standalone JFrame would be best as many different input types are needed (checkbox etc), didn't know you could do as much as that with JOptionPane. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Maniek, is it possible to display more than one option on the same JOptionPane? I don't want 10 different popups happening, just one that contains the multiple inputs. E.g. one winow asking for Forename, Surname, a tickbox and so on?

Comment: Oh, i get it now. I do not think so, that we can use JOptionPane with more than one option, however there is one - probably not elegant way to do this. You can create Object Settings with over overriden toString() method - then you can put array of your setting objects in different configuration into JOptionPane.
If this do not satisfy your expectations you can allways create new JFrame with reference to main JFrame. 'Settings s = new Settings(JFrame mainFrame);' Then you will get full access for variables in main frame.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, dynamic application settings are supplied by some sort of "admin" user in an application (at least based on what I've seen after 5 years of corporate application development).  I'm not sure how complicated your application is, but for a simple application, a screen with key/value pairs for inputting application settings would be a "standard" route to go.

Answer (score 0):

As Maniek said, the JOptionPane is the easiest way to capture input from a user in a separate box. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

But if you're attempting to create a new window for settings, you have to initialize the JFrame. I would set it up my button like so:

```
       Settings test = new Settings();                   // creates a new window
       test.setSize(400, 300 );                  // sets the size
       test.setVisible( true );                  // makes it visible
```

Because when you just call "new Settings()" I don't think it does that.